# Finding the root of a nested function with small values

Tags: equation-solving

I have reduced an error in my program to this line of code:

```
FindRoot[Nest[# (1 - #) k &, 1/2, 2^4] - 1/2, {k, 3.5}]
```

It works for $2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4,$ but then for $2^n, n\ge5,$ it stops. Nothing happens. *Mathematica* is "thinking" forever. `FindRoot` is not doing a single iteration.

Why does this happen?

I have some ideas of my own, none of which have gotten me anywhere:

1. The values are very small, is it a precision problem?
2. Maybe I'm not using `Nest` properly?

Comment: You do realize that you trying to find the root for polynomial of order **2^2^n**? So for n=5 it's **4294967296** order!

Comment: To speed things up a bit I suggest to `Expand` your expression and `Chop` the small parts at every nesting: `Nest[Chop[Expand[# (1 - #) k]] &, 0.5, 2^4] - 0.5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a purely numeric function so that `FindRoot` cannot do anything fancy with the symbolic form. This can be done as below.

```
ff[k_?NumberQ] := Nest[# (1 - #) k &, 1/2, 2^4]

FindRoot[ff[k] == 1/2, {k, 3.5}]

(* Out[22]= {k -> 3.49856169933}` *)
```